This might be habitual use but grammatically incorrect
习近平主席说，我在这里既感受到布达佩斯的历史传统，又看到了新的生机活力，加深了对匈牙利的认知，留下了一段珍贵的记忆。时隔15年，匈牙利取得的发展成就令我印象深刻。(news report of May 12, Xinhua News Agency)
With the "令我印象深刻", his excellency wants to say the achievement of Hungary is impressive on me or I am impressed, but the words given literally mean that I impress you very much (what I did is impressive or I am impressive), so it should be changed to be "给我留下了深刻的印象".
Do you agree?

Maybe he wanted to say 令我(對它的)印象(十分)深刻 (people omit a lot in casual conversations)

The relevant grammar here is:

令 + [noun] + [verb]
令 + [noun] + [adjective]

Since 深刻 is an adjective, let's focus on adjectives, but note that Chinese adjectives normally also function as verbs (there's a few adjectives like this in English, such as in "wet the floor" and "brown the onions").
Common usages are:

令我惊讶 (made me surprised)
令她不安 (made her uneasy)
令他恶心 (made him nauseous)
令我女儿高兴 (made my daughter happy)

In the given example, we have

令 + 我印象 + 深刻  (made my impression deep)

It's grammatical in Chinese, but it sounds weird if we directly translate into English.  So we might instead translate it to:

匈牙利取得的发展成就令我印象深刻。
[Google Translate]: I am deeply impressed by Hungary’s development achievements.

The version you suggest is also correct, and it's the one I was taught while studying Chinese:

……给我留下了深刻的印象。


I don't see any issue with it.  To me its a pretty obvious as 我I 印象have it stay on my mind 深刻 very deeply.
I could see the phrase being interpreted different ways that you mentioned without context, but can't see them at all that way with the context.  I don't think there is any error in the speech structured this way, and even without the context it would be my go to way to read it.

令我印象深刻 doesn't mean "I impress you very much."
Instead:

令：make/cause;
我：me;
印象深刻：(adjective) "deeply impressed"

Hence, "[cause] [me] [deeply impressed]" -> "caused me to be deeply impressed" -> "left a deep/profound impression on me."
Hence, "匈牙利取得的发展成就令我印象深刻" -> "Hungary's developmental achievements left a deep/profound impression on me."
Note: "给我留下了深刻的印象" is, of course, also correct in this context.

Not so:

but the words given literally mean that I impress you very much

Nobody would say "I impress you very much" in China. It is immodest.
历史传统: history and traditions or historical tradition(s)??
印象深刻: profoundly impressed or a profound impression??
令我[印象深刻]: leaves me [how], leaves me [deeply impressed]
习近平主席说，
Chairman Xi said,
我在这里既感受到布达佩斯的历史传统，
being here I can already feel Budapest's history and traditions,
又看到了新的生机活力，
and (I) see new opportunities and energy,
加深了对匈牙利的认知，
deepening (my) perception of Hungary,
留下了一段珍贵的记忆。
leaving behind a precious memory.
时隔15年，
After 15 years, (since my last visit)
匈牙利取得的发展成就令我印象深刻。
Hungary has developed and achieved a success which leaves me deeply impressed.
or
Hungary has developed and achieved a success which leaves a deep impression on me.

The grammar here is perfectly fine and is not some kind of abridged version of either 令我的印象深刻 or 给我留下了深刻的印象 (although it means those things and could be rephrased in those ways, and in other ways still).
The grammar in the original sentence is a causative structure, and it goes like this:

发展成就+令我+印象深刻

whereby 「印象深刻」(a state of being deeply impressed) is stirred into「我」by「发展成就」(developmental achievements). In other words, those achievements + have caused him + (to feel in such a way as) to be (struck) deep (with an) impression.
The best way to 'unfold' the sentence in more explicit terms is Tang Ho's suggestion of "令我(對它的)印象(十分)深刻" - bearing in mind that the underlying structure of the sentence, as it was originally stated, remains 令我 + [(對它的)印象+(十分)深刻].

『时隔15年，匈牙利取得的发展成就令我印象深刻』
时隔15年，After 15 years ,
匈牙利取得的发展成就令我印象深刻 :
(匈牙利取得的发展&成就)令我印象深刻
令我印象深刻 ← (匈牙利取得的发展&成就)
令我印象深刻 :　I was impressed  (by ... ← 匈牙利取得的发展&成就)
I was impressed   by 匈牙利(15年來)的发展&成就
In Chinese, the word impress, 印象深刻, not only descript on the human/landscapes, but also on what you have done.
Generally speaking, the word '令我印象深刻' is equal to "给我(留下了)深刻的印象"
